# VS2008: How to display nested include file hierarchy in case of error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, include-path

Does VS2008's C++ compiler have something simuilar to gcc's include file hierarchy error feature? In the case of an error in an include file detected deep in a nested include file hierarchy, gcc lists  the include file hierarchy path. Something along the lines of (from memory)

```
Error detected in file FileD.h while compiling FileA.cpp
FileD.h.h included from FileC.h
FileC.h.h included from FileB.h
FileB.h.h included from FileA.h
```

This allows me to see how FileD.h is related to FileA.cpp. Sorry, I don't have access to gcc here at work, to show a realistic example.

I know about VS2008's related feature:

```
ProjectProperties -> Configuration -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> ShowIncludes
```

But this shows the complete nested include file hierarchy, which is too much detail in the case of an error.